# From which controller should I be using to update these models, and how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested-attributes

Here are the 3 models I am using:

user.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  email           :string(255)
#  remember_token  :string(255)
#  password_digest :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :jobs
  has_many :restaurants, :through => :jobs

end
```

job.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: jobs
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  restaurant_id :integer
#  shortname     :string(255)
#  user_id       :integer
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :restaurant_id, :shortname, :user_id

  belongs_to    :user
  belongs_to    :restaurant
  has_many      :shifts

end
```

restaurant.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: restaurants
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many    :jobs
  has_many    :users, :through => :jobs
  has_many    :positions

end
```

My scenario is that the user is already created and entered into the user table, however now the user wants to:

- Possibly create a new restaurant, if it doesn't exist already
- Create a link between the user and the restaurant through the jobs table and

  - Possibly create a nickname in the jobs table at the same time

I will be using a Nested Model in a form to accomplish this, however I removed all code relevant to that at the moment. The reason is that I was trying to create the records from within the Restaurants_Controller, which as you can see is at the bottom of the "chain". Thinking about it, this seems wrong. I could get rails to do it's magic for everything but linking the user_id in the job model.

Anyway, I think i'm not understanding Rails at a higher level. Where should the logic for saving the above be (as a result of a person hitting "Submit" on a form)?

Answer (score 1):

> Possibly create a new restaurant, if it doesn't exist already

I think that's the key here. A user isn't *necessarily* creating a restaurant in the flow you're imagining. She's creating a job, which I take it is partly a relationship between a user and a restaurant (which also has some other knowledge about that user's shifts at the restaurant).

It's not clear to me that a nested form is the right solution here in the long run, but from what you've described I'm imagining a user going to the jobs/new view, which contains a form that posts to jobs#create, which creates a relationship between that user and a restaurant. Figuring out where the restaurant_id comes from and where in the flow to create not-yet-persisted restaurants seems to be the next thing to figure out.

Comment: thanks, i'm not sure either. I'd love to hear the rest of your thoughts, i'm soaking it up!

Comment: I think you're getting into user experience questions at this point. Some options: have a way of selecting a restaurant in the form, and pass in `params[:restaurant_id]` as the value of the field. Allow this to be `nil`, and then you need logic in your controller to decide what to do if it is. Do you redirect to a restaurant creation page (maybe *this* is your nested form)? Or perhaps you have an "add new restaurant" button on the page that loads in additional form elements for creating the restaurant through javascript, rather than letting `params[:restaurant_id]` be `nil`. Lots of options.

Comment: I'd upvote you but I can't.. yet. Also, I obviously need to understand Ruby/Rails more.
Thanks!

Comment: Stick with it! You're asking good questions. I've only been doing Rails development for a few months myself. If not I'd probably have stronger opinions about what the right solution is!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use rails resources for these things. Rails resource provide you different urls for different field.
use it like this in config/routes.rb

```
resources :restaurent do
 resources :job 
end
```

This will create update urls for restuarent and jobs, with jobs nested.
If you are not aware of resources, read about it in the rails guide